# The Force-model in physics is just one interpretation of the natural world. Are their other interpretations other than the force model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, special-relativity

I'm a high school physics student and almost every concept I've learned has involved the concept of force. But forces are just one way to view the world. Newton believed that something (force) pulled the apple down from the tree, but another person might have thought something entirely different. So, my question is this -
What interpretations of the natural world are there except for the force model? Also, what makes the forces model a better interpretation of the natural world than other interpretations?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the force-based model is an energy-based model,
such as "The Principle of Least Action" (as described in the Feynman lectures: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html ).

Related to the force-based model is
a momentum-flow-model, e.g.,
Andrea A. diSessa
"Momentum flow as an alternative perspective in elementary mechanics"
American Journal of Physics 48, 365 (1980);
https://doi.org/10.1119/1.12106

In some situations, one model might be easier to interpret, or calculate,
or extend to other similar systems.